# DataGrid catch cell value changed event with a single click on UpdateSourceTrigger = SourceUpdated

Tags: wpf, events, datagrid

I'm struggling to catch an event with a DataGrid. What I want to achieve is that when the user clicks ONCE on a checkbox of a datagrid cell, an event fires and I can get the current cell value. However the CellChangedEvent fires only when the selection changes, and the CellEditingEvent either fires when the cell loses focus, OR never fires. It never fires if I try to make a checkbox modificable with a single click, by doing the following:

```
<DataGrid Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding MasterDataTable, Mode=TwoWay}" CanUserAddRows="False" Margin="10 5" CurrentCellChanged="DataGrid_CurrentCellChanged">
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="IsEditing" Value="True" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.Resources>
        </DataGrid>
```

How can I call a method as soon as the user clicks on a checkbox inside a cell?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you have a cell edit template or a DataGridColumn to post ?
I think the issue is binding it with UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChange on the cell's binding value .

Comment: I wish I had, unfortunately I auto generate columns. The item source is bound to a DataView object.

Comment: ok so first thing you need is to not AutoGenerate the columns 
you wan't a "Special" behavior for your DataGrid which has to be customized , It's a special behavior because DataGrid's default behavior is to update binding values on LostFocus and not on the common PropertyChanged setting .

Comment: OK I'll try that out. What about making a single click of the cell changing the checkbox value without losing the possibilty of using the CellEditingFinished event?

Comment: Now that you mention it i don't believe CellEditingFinished would fire  before lost focus either way , what is it you are trying to base on that ? 
and why is lost focus not good for this matter ?

Comment: Basically I want this behaviour: as soon as you click on a checkbox a method is called and sets several checkboxes (out of the datagrid) to the value of that cell.

Comment: O'k i'll post an Answer for you what you need is the use of NotifyOnPropertyChangedEvent

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1) In your DataGrid register for **TargetUpdated** event .

2) Specify a Column , and ideally set **AutoGenerateColumns=False** .

3) In your Binding flag the **NotifyOnTargetUpdated** property (your target is your checkbox).

4) In your Binding **UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged** and **Mode=TwoWay** (not the default behavior of the DataGrid).

XAML :

```
 <DataGrid TargetUpdated="DataGrid_TargetUpdated" 
           AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
           ItemsSource="{Binding SomeValues, Mode=OneWay}"  CanUserAddRows="False"  >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding Path=.,  NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="*"/>                        
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

in CS: (where you might wan't to handle that event.)

```
   private void DataGrid_TargetUpdated(object sender, DataTransferEventArgs e)
   {
         // Do what ever...
   }
```

Comment: Thank for your answer, but it works partially. Infact the target updated handler is called also when it loads data which isn't modified by the user. Any workaround?

Comment: That's a good question we need an indication of when the ItemsSource was fully loaded so we can register to NotifyOnTargetUpdated there .

Comment: Actually I have solved it by checking if CurrentCell and CurrentCell.Column aren't null (considering that I only fill the DataGrid as soon as the application boots, otherwise I would have no idea of how to do it). Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Happy to help , but still you've  raised an interesting point ,when i found out how i'll post a better and complete soulotion .

Comment: Thank you. Right now I came across another problem. As I move my mouse pointer over the cell the trigger raises the TargetUpdated event (because IsEditable is set to true, I think). That's pretty annoying considering the method is called several times. I'm going to try to play around with the event args.

Comment: Do you have to have a CellEditTemplate in your solution 
If it's not mandatory you can use a DataGridTemplateColumn with only a CellTemplate and you wouldn't have to deal with all the hassle of maintaining an Edit and a ReadOnly state for your cells.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved it. It's not the best of the solution but it works for me.
As stated by @eranotzap I set set AutoGenerateColumns=False and UpdateSourceTrigger = PropertyChanged. Then I did the following:

```
<DataGrid Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" 
          AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding MasterDataTable, Mode=TwoWay}" 
          CanUserAddRows="False" 
          Margin="10 5">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Fornitore}" Header="Fornitore" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Stat}" Header="Stat" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Intestazione}" Header="Intestazione" Width="*" IsReadOnly="True" >
        <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
            </Style>
        </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        <DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
            <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
                <Setter Property="AcceptsReturn" Value="true" />
            </Style>
        </DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=PrzVend}" Header="PrzVend" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=DatEXPO}" Header="DatEXPO" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Sel, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=False, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="Sel" Width="Auto">
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                    <EventSetter Event="CheckBox.Checked" Handler="CellChanged"/>
                    <EventSetter Event="CheckBox.Unchecked" Handler="CellChanged"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
                                <Condition Property="IsReadOnly" Value="False" />
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="IsEditing" Value="True" />
                        </MultiTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style> 
            </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.CellStyle>
        </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=CodComp}" Header="CodComp" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

In the code behind the method CellChanges is called every time the checkbox is checked or unchecked. To get the value I do the following:

```
void CellChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender as DataGridCell != null && (sender as DataGridCell).Column != null && (sender as DataGridCell).Column.Header != null)
    {

        bool? isSelected = (e.OriginalSource as ToggleButton).IsChecked;

    }
}
```

Hope it helps somebody.

Answer (score 1):

Try this simple way

```
private void myDataGrid_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Column.SortMemberPath.Equals("EndDate"))
        {
            if (((MyObjectInRow)e.Row.Item).DataFine.Equals(EndDate.MinValue))
            {
                ((MyObjectInRow)e.Row.Item).Completed = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                ((MyObjectInRow)e.Row.Item).Completed = 0;
            }


        }
    }
```