# Prevent checkbox events of datagrid being triggered when itemsource has been changed

Tags: c#, wpf, events, checkbox, datagrid

I have a datagrid with various cells (one cell is a checkbox). There is a checkbox event (checked & unchecked) that I use to add x amount to the global balance account (textbox). The data is only valid for a year, so if I change the current year (by combobox selection) to evaluate or check something I change the datasource (`ObservableCollection<Member>`) of the datagrid.

I expect that when I load a new datasource that only the data within the datagrid is being exchanged.

What is actually happening is that when I load a new datasource (different list) into the datagrid all checked & unchecked events are being called therefore changing the balance value of the textbox.

How can I prevent those events being called. Is there something like a very last event that I can use to set a flag ("newSourceInitialized") to enable the check events so they will only be triggered when the user actually clicks them?

WPF Code goes here:

```xml
<Grid x:Name="MainGrid">
    <Grid x:Name="Navbar" Background="#FFADECED" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
            <!--A column for every item in navbar grid must be added here-->
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="Aktuelles Jahr" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="left" />
        <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Name="cbxYear" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="left" SelectionChanged="cbxYearSelectionChanged" ContextMenuClosing="cbxLostFocus" />
        <Button Grid.Column="2" Name="btnAddNewYear" BorderBrush="Transparent" Background="Transparent" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="left">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Margin="5,0,0,0" Source="/data/images/add-24-blue.png" Stretch="None"/>
                <TextBlock Margin="5,0,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"><Run Text="Neues Jahr"/></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>
        <Button Grid.Column="3"  Name="btnSave" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" Click="btnSave_Click" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="left">
            <DynamicResource ResourceKey="unsaved"/>
        </Button>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="4" Name="tbxBalance" TextChanged="textBoxNumeric_TextChanged" TextAlignment="Right" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="left" Width="151"/>

    </Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="MainPane">
        <!-- loaded event necessary cause otherwise checked events will be triggered -> changing the balance -->
        <DataGrid Name="dgMembers" d:ItemsSource="{d:SampleData ItemCount=5}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="0,27,0,0" Loaded="gridLoaded">
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF96BFF5"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,1,2"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.Resources>

            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding Path=id}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Vorname" Binding="{Binding Path=firstname}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Nachname" Binding="{Binding Path=lastname}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Geburtstag" Binding="{Binding Path=birthday, StringFormat={}\{0:dd.MM.yyyy\}}"/>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox Name="cbxPayed" IsChecked="{Binding Path=payed}" Checked="cbxPayedChecked" Unchecked="cbxPayedUnchecked" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Bemerkung" Binding="{Binding Path=note}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

C# Code

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window {
    ObservableCollection<Member> lstMembers;
    private int MemberDue;
    private bool isInitialized = false;
    private bool hasChangesToBeSaved = true;//TODO start with false
    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
        initializeData();
    }

    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        if (hasChangesToBeSaved) { btnSave.Content = FindResource(btnSave.Content == FindResource("unsaved") ? "saved" : "unsaved"); }
        saveEverything();
    }
    private async Task saveEverything() {
        await io.saveMembers(lstMembers, "2023");// io is a class for json reading and writing
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        hasChangesToBeSaved = false;
    }

    private void initializeData() {
        cbxYear.ItemsSource = io.getAllFiles();
        cbxYear.SelectedIndex = 0;
        loadData();
    }

    private void loadData() {
        lstMembers = io.readMembers(cbxYear.SelectedValue.ToString());
        dgMembers.ItemsSource = lstMembers;
        MemberDue = Convert.ToInt32(Properties.Settings.Default.MemberDue);
        tbxBalance.Text += Properties.Settings.Default.Balance;
        isInitialized = true;
    }

    private void gridLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        isInitialized = true;
    }

    private void cbxYearSelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (isInitialized) {
            isInitialized = false; // prevent check events being executed while data is loading

            loadData();
        }
    }
    
    private void cbxLostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        isInitialized = true;
    }

    private void cbxPayedUnchecked(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (isInitialized) {
            string balance = tbxBalance.Text.Equals(String.Empty) ? "0" : tbxBalance.Text;
            tbxBalance.Text = (Convert.ToDouble(balance) - MemberDue).ToString();
        }
    }
    
    private void cbxPayedChecked(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (isInitialized) {
            string balance = tbxBalance.Text.Equals(String.Empty) ? "0" : tbxBalance.Text;
            tbxBalance.Text = (Convert.ToDouble(balance) + MemberDue).ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

For now I block the check events at startup and reactivate them with the "loaded" event of the datagrid. This works for the startup. Now I want the same thing for the datasource changed function that I use to load a different year.

Comment: Would you mind to go more into detail about what you expect and what is happening? It is not clear what's going on. Normally changing the data source instance does not result in UI events being raised. For example, check boxes get ticked based on the IsChecked value but this won't raise the Checked event. This is because new item containers will be created when you change the source. The new values are assigned to the dependency properties during the initialization routine of the dependency object. During this routine there won't be any events .

Comment: Also post a minimal example that reproduces your issue. This helps to understand what you are doing.

Comment: I updated the question. Hope it's a better description of the problem I'm having.

Comment: @Prouder: Did you try to set the `isInitialized` flag to `false` before you set the `ItemsSource`, i.e. on the first line in your `loadData` method?

Comment: @mm8 yes I did. I do it in the "cbxYearSelectionChanged" function that calls the "loadData" function again to change the current year. I debugged it and the check events are being called after the data source is changed thus changing the calculation afterwards.

Comment: @Prouder: When does the issue occur? At what line in the code? Could you please provide a minimal reproducible sample?

Comment: It's already a minimal reproduction. All events are necessary for initial loading and change of datasource. To clarify what happens. After initial loading the checkevents will be blocked by isInitialized = false. isInitialized will become true once the grid is fully loaded "gridLoaded() comes from Loaded WPF" after all checkevents have been called. This doesn't work when I select a different datasource by calling cbxYearSelectionChanged() which calls loadData() again because gridLoaded() is only called once in application lifecycle, when everything concerning the grid is loaded.

Comment: @mm8 Right now when changing the datasource the checkevents are the last being called. When initially loading the last event is the Loaded WPF -> gridLoaded() event. Therefore working with the isInitialized flag did the job for the initial loading phase. Now I wanna do the same with the datasource changed state caused by the combobox. But I don't know any event being triggered like Loaded that comes after the check events. Hope that describes what the problem and what I wanna do better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was as simple as confusing. I set "isInitialized = false" before I load a new source and set "isInitialized = true" when the source is updated.

I also changed  "AutoGenerateColumns="False" and removed d:ItemsSource="{d:SampleData ItemCount=5}".
this helped a little: [DataGrid catch cell value changed event with a single click on UpdateSourceTrigger = SourceUpdated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20174094/datagrid-catch-cell-value-changed-event-with-a-single-click-on-updatesourcetrigg)

Now when I load a new source the balance textbox get's another "0" for each reload although the value is actually "0" but that is a different topic that has nothing to do with this.